# '[AnyObject]?' is not convertible to 'NSArray'

Tags: xcode, swift

error is in let USER part 
i am using new swift1.2
please help
[AnyObject] is not convertible to NSArray

```
var PostData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func loadData(){
    PostData.removeAllObjects()

    var findPostData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

    findPostData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                let post:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.PostData.addObject(post)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.PostData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.PostData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Postcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostscaamTableViewCell

    let post:PFObject = self.PostData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    postcell.postTimelineTextView.alpha = 0
    postcell.timeStamp.alpha = 0
    postcell.usernameLabel3.alpha = 0

    postcell.postTimelineTextView.text = post.objectForKey("Content") as! String

    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm"
    postcell.timeStamp.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt!)

    var findPostedBy:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

    findPostedBy.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("Postedby")!)

    findPostedBy.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects, error)->Void in
        if error == nil {
            let USER:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
                postcell.usernameLabel3.text = USER.username

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                postcell.postTimelineTextView.alpha = 1
                postcell.timeStamp.alpha = 1
                postcell.usernameLabel3.alpha = 1

            })
        }
    }

     return postcell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Postcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostscaamTableViewCell

    let post:PFObject = self.PostData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    postcell.postTimelineTextView.alpha = 0
    postcell.timeStamp.alpha = 0
    postcell.usernameLabel3.alpha = 0

    postcell.postTimelineTextView.text = post.objectForKey("Content") as! String

    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm"
    postcell.timeStamp.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(post.createdAt!)

    var findPostedBy:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

    findPostedBy.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post.objectForKey("Postedby")!)

    findPostedBy.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let users : [PFUser] = objects as? [PFUser] where users.count > 0 {
            let USER:PFUser = users.last!
                postcell.usernameLabel3.text = USER.username


                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                    postcell.postTimelineTextView.alpha = 1
                    postcell.timeStamp.alpha = 1
                    postcell.usernameLabel3.alpha = 1

                })
            }
        }
    }
    return postcell
}
```

Comment: If it is working, accept the answer. It will help others as correct answer.

Comment: @Amit89 one more problem my post data is not being displayed i have tried to fix this but nothing is happening and no error is coming i think in swift 1.2 there is different method to display data from parse

Comment: For that you need to check Array content, if your array does not contain data how will you show? You have to debug using breakpoint or printing in the console.

Comment: @Amit89 ok now it is working  but only usernameLabel3 is not displaying i am  trying to debug

Comment: hey please help me in getting my label work i want help

Comment: Check the count of users Array. Print it println(users.count). If it is greater than zero, then println(USER). I doubt wether USER has value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try forced downcasting, such as `(objects as! NSArray)`.

Comment: [AnyObject] to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails